# Gstreamer, appsrc -> demuxer? (Trying to play VOB with audio)

Tags: c, gstreamer

I assume that a pipeline should work that looks something like

```
                    |-> mpeg2dec -> autovideosink
appsrc -> dvddemux =
                    |-> ac3parse -> a52dec -> audioconvert -> autoaudiosink
```

correct? The pipeline seems to build fine, but for some reason the "need-data" and "enough-data" signals are not firing off. They worked fine before when it was just a pipeline of

```
appsrc -> dvddemux -> mpeg2dec -> autovideosink
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: It must be that my pipeline is erroneous because I tried simply:

`gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=/myfile.vob typefind=true ! dvddemux name=demux demux.video_00 ! mpeg2dec ! autovideosink demux.audio_00 ! ac3parse ! a52dec ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink`

and received the error **`ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a queue after the demuxer in both branches.

Comment: Hi, would you mind explaining how that would resolve OP's issue? As it currently stands, it's hard to understand your answer.

Comment: I did some research after reading his answer. From [Basic Tutorial #7](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+7%3A+Multithreading+and+Pad+Availability) of the gstreamer docs: "As seen in the picture, queues create a new thread, so this pipeline runs in 3 threads. Pipelines with more than one sink usually need to be multithreaded, because, to be synchronized, sinks usually block execution until all other sinks are ready, and they cannot get ready if there is only one thread, being blocked by the first sink."

I'll report back when I resolve the issue though.

Comment: Yup, it worked. Thank you so much, Zaheer!